# flask-migrate wants to drop my indeces

Tags: python, flask, alembic, flask-migrate

I've got a Flask app with the following models:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    city_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('cities.id'))

class City(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cities'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    user_ids = db.relationship('User', backref='city', lazy='dynamic')
```

I've run a migration to specify my indices and foreign key constraints:

```
def upgrade():
    op.create_foreign_key('fk_user_city', "users", "cities", ["city_id"], ["id"])
    op.create_index('city_idx', 'users', ['city_id'])
```

However, any time I create another new migration Alembic seems to want to drop my indexes.

Is there a way to freeze Alembic's autogeneration at the current DB/Model schema?

Comment: Please include the command you do to migrate, and the generated migration files.

Comment: Almebic tries to drop your index because it is not specified in your ORM model. You could add the index by specifying

    city_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('cities.id'), index=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html) page. You will need to change env.py under migrations folder.

```
EnvironmentContext.configure.include_object
```

or

```
EnvironmentContext.configure.include_schemas
```

should be what you are looking for.